# Flutter check list is not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a list that has a behaviour that i tried to make it look like a check box. The code snippet is as follows. Im using Getx for state management and the widget is denoted with a Obx.

**Code Snippet**

```
*this is the list item widget*
Widget buildChecks() {
    final controller = Get.find<SPController>();
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Obx(
          () =>
              controller.searchResults.isNotEmpty &&
                      controller.searchResults[index].selected!.value
                  ? 
                  IconButton(
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      tooltip: "Click to Remove Location",
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.check_box_rounded,
                        color: AppColors.secondary,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                         function 001 
                        controller.searchResults[index].selected!.value = false;
                        controller.update();
                      },
                    )
                  :
                  IconButton(
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      tooltip: "Click to Add Location",
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_rounded),
                      onPressed: () async {
                         function 002 
                        controller.searchResults[index].selected!.value = true;
                        controller.update();
                        *//// added to update a list *
                        final dsf = Dsf(
                            idDsf: result.idDsf,
                            name: result.name,
                            address: result.address,
                            createdAt: DateTime.now());
                        controller.selectedList.add(dsf);
                      },
                    ),
        ));
  }
```

My list is defined as an RxList<>.
In function 001, when that icon is pressed the list updated the icon and changes accordingly.
But when i add more code like in function 002 (code to add to a list) the check box icon is not updated/changed.

Can someone help me out here with this so when user click on either icon it will change the icon and also run the code to add or remove the selected list item?  i did debug alot of options but for no vail. Thank you.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow james
1- your code contain many typo errors
2 - please post a run-able code, this going to help another members to check your code faster